# css3 news-headlines auto scroll up

Tags: javascript, html, css

So marquee is deprecated in html5. I have written the code for news headlines which should automatically start from the top news first then slowly scroll upwards. Once the last news is gone, the first one should append to the last one and appear like one continuous flow. This should iterate continuously. Currently my code starts from a blank div, the news start pouring in from the bottom. And there is a gap between the last news and the first news headline. How can I achieve this?:-

Here is the code snippet:

```css
#mid_section_2{
      
      border-top:3px solid black;
      border-bottom:3px solid black;
      border-right:1px dotted black;
      border-left:1px dotted black;
      background-color:white;
      overflow:hidden;
      height:200px;
     }

#mid_section_2 h5{
      border:1px solid black;
    }
    
    
    #up{
      padding-top:100%;
      padding-left:5%;
      padding-right:5%;
      animation-name: myanimate;
      animation-duration: 10s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-timing-function:linear;
    }
    
    @keyframes myanimate{
      from{transform:translate(0,0)}
      to{transform:translate(0,-100%)}
    }
```

```html
<div id="mid_section_2">
        <div id="up">
          <a href="#"><h6>EU officials sees end of the road for diesel cars.</h6></a>
          <h6>Tata expects combined sales output of 850,000 units by next FY.</h6>
          <h6>Maruti Dzire AMT accounts for 17% of total sales.</h6>
          <h6>EESL to roll out 1,000 electric cars to Maharashtra government</h6>
          <h6>Tata expects combined sales output of 850,000 units by next FY.</h6>
          <h6>Maruti Dzire AMT accounts for 17% of total sales.</h6>
          <h6>EESL to roll out 1,000 electric cars to Maharashtra government</h6>
          
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You need to use script in your case...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(function(){
  var tickerLength = $('.container ul li').length;
  var tickerHeight = $('.container ul li').outerHeight();
  $('.container ul li:last-child').prependTo('.container ul');
  $('.container ul').css('marginTop',-tickerHeight);
  function moveTop(){
    $('.container ul').animate({
      top : -tickerHeight
    },600, function(){
     $('.container ul li:first-child').appendTo('.container ul');
      $('.container ul').css('top','');
    });
   }
  setInterval( function(){
    moveTop();
  }, 3000);
  });
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  font-family:'tahoma', serif;
}
.container{
  width:260px;
  margin:20px auto;
  height:300px;
  background-color:#333;
  overflow:hidden;
}
ul{
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
}
li{
  height:100px;
  background-color:rgba(57, 173, 117,0.3);
   text-align:center;
  border-bottom:1px solid #333;
}
h2{
  color:#fff;
  padding-top:10px;
}
p{
  text-align:left;
  padding:10px;
  color:#eee;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h2>Head line 1</h2>
      <p>News detail just a line jhghdsbd hsdssdhjhdjshdjsahdjs</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>Head line 2</h2>
      <p>News detail just a line jhghdsbd hsdssdhjhdjshdjsahdjs</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>Head line 3</h2>
      <p>News detail just a line jhghdsbd hsdssdhjhdjshdjsahdjs</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>Head line 4</h2>
      <p>News detail just a line jhghdsbd hsdssdhjhdjshdjsahdjs</p>
    </li>
   
    
  </ul>
</div>
```